# Finding null values when I write a query in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I have just written the following query and gotten a surprise (to me) result;

```
Customer.where("satisfaction != ?","Very satisfied")
```

This returned far fewer values than I expected and the reason turns out to be null values in the database for my satisfaction column. To get the records I want I have to write the following query

```
Customer.where("satisfaction != ? or satisfaction is null","Very satisfied")
```

This works but it's ugly and I'm hoping there's a better way (especially as I plan on generating these queries dynamically so I want them to be as simple as possible). Is there an operator that incorporates null values along with unequal values?

My database is SQLite3 in development and Postgresql in production.

Comment: Which environment produced the surprising result?

Comment: SQLite3 produced the surprising result

Comment: So will any database that even pretends to pay lip service to the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you could use [IS DISTINCT FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) to get around the usual NULL issues:

```
Customer.where('satisfaction is distinct from ?', 'Very satisfied')
```

In SQLite I think you're stuck with your explicit IS NULL check or an equally ugly COALESCE:

```
Customer.where("coalesce(satisfaction, '') != ?", 'Very satisfied')
```

COALESCE evaluates to its first non-NULL argument and will work in both SQLite and PostgreSQL; you can use anything that won't match your `'Very satisfied'` in place of the empty string.

I'd strongly recommend that you stop developing on top of SQLite when you're deploying on top of PostgreSQL. You're just asking for a bad time on production server when SQLite's lax interpretation of SQL conflicts with PostgreSQL's stricter interpretation. Don't do this to yourself, develop and deploy using the same database (where *same* includes the version number).

You might also want to revisit your schema to see if you can add a NOT NULL constraint to your `satisfaction` column. An explicit `'Unknown'` string might serve just as well and would avoid the usual NULL nonsense. I tend to manually default everything to NOT NULL and only allow NULLs if I can justify it.

Comment: I've learned the develop and deploy on the same db lesson the hard way already. It is my current practice but this is an old app I'm revisiting. Thanks for the great answer once again.

Comment: A null is clearly not wanted here. The value is presumably "no answer" or similar. It's a shame the column-default in SQL isn't NOT NULL.

Comment: @RichardHuxton: And its a shame that ActiveRecord propagates this poor default.